# use of sql database in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have created a database using sqlite file . How to access sqlite file in Android and where to keep that db file in android project.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I would start by reading this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand the database you have created is on your computer, and you want to bundle it in your APK. Therefore, I suggest you use a library such as https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper , and load your database from assets. Also, I suggest you read the documentation for SQLite: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html

Answer (score 0):

You can keep it in assets folder. ALso you can use this method to copy your .db file into system database:

```
private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.example.testapp/databases/";

private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

    this.getReadableDatabase();
    //Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(this.dbName);

    // Path to the just created empty db
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + this.dbName;

    //Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    //Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();

}
```